# Market Exposure and Hedging

Tags: risk-management, hedging, futures, market

Normally the Market exposure associated with your stock/portfolio is your delta for that stock/ portfolio. Basic idea of hedging involved here is buying/selling respective futures depending upon whether you are short or long. Right now I just use one single future traded on stock exchange to hedge against all kind of exposure, whether it's a sector or country exposure.

In some cases, my future doesn't always has stock components for all sectors, like it may be missing some mining stocks. There are days when such sector can move by a large percentage. I basically want to minimize my risk for these days, for which I can manually buy the exchange traded sector specific future but then certain sectors have inter correlation with each other. So buying one may not be the best way but instead some combination of 2-3 futures which can minimize my exposure as much as possible.

Basically, what I am trying to do is select some 2-3 futures (may be ETFS) which can reduce my market exposure to as low as possible? How can I select those 2-3 ETFs/Futures from my universe of say 9-10?

The problem can be solved by either iterating over all the possible combination of futures (present in my universe)  or coming up with some function for market exposure that can be minimized under certain constraint. I hope I am clear in what I am trying to accomplish or may be someone can help me to refine the problem statement, if they get the idea.

I am looking for some suggestions on how to continue or what could be a good objective function that could be minimized in this case.

Thank you.

Comment: you should look at sector ETFs, which should solve your problem.

Comment: @Freddy
We can't afford to use ETFs given the fact that we only do Day trading and ETFs aren't considered to be a good instrument for short trading horizon.

Comment: I do not see how they are not good short term instruments. Many are traded with tight enough spreads and with deep enough liquidity to rival large cap stocks.

Comment: @Freddy
I did some research on ETFs and find out that they can be used also. 
I would like to know why sector specific ETFs over futures?
What I am trying to do is select some 2-3 futures (may be ETFS) which can reduce my market exposure to as low as possible? How can I select those 2-3 ETFs/Futures from my universe of say 9-10? Using brute force method by trying different possible combination is something I want to avoid.

Comment: You should then change your question. What you actually like to ask is hardly explained in the above

Comment: Do you know what a *risk model* is, or how to do *principal component analysis*? It sounds like you just want to hedge against few *factors*. So pick some sector ETFs that replicate your portfolio's primary risk factors.

Comment: @chrisaycock
Yeah I have decent bit idea of of risk model & PCA. But I think if I run PCA over my portfolio it will pick some factors which will only work for regular days but not for days when some sector is making huge losses. I am looking for a hedging strategy which can work on some specific days because on normal days buying a stock index future works fine. Anyway I will try to run PCA and see what I get.
Thanks for the suggestion.